# PHP GD: Bad quality on resize?

Tags: php

I dont like the resized image i get out,

```
imagecopyresized($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

ImageJpeg ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext", 100);
```

I added 100 in ImageJpeg, because i wish to improve the quality, but it didnt get any better.

How can i improve the quality on resized images/thumbnails

Comment: https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/99

Answer (score 29):

Try using [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) instead. That does interpolation, which will make things look a lot nicer.

Comment: Also make sure to use imagecreatetruecolor(), when creating $new_img

Comment: If you read the PHP manual, I'm pretty sure it mentioned using the above two functions is highly recommended.

Answer (score 8):

Since PHP 5.5, you can use **imagesetinterpolation** to determine the way your images are interpolated during transformations (typically, *scaling and resampling*, but also *rotations,* etc.).

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetinterpolation.php

For image **downsampling,** you probably want to use the **IMG_SINC** algorithm, it tends to give crisper results. For rotation as well.

For upsampling, IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED, IMG_GENERALIZED_CUBIC and IMG_QUADRATIC might give the better results. Ultimately you'll have to test them: set this option on newly created image resources as soon as possible, combine it with the high quality flag when saving jpegs, and you should be pretty free from artifacts when using GD.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for past versions like PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 5):

try using [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

I use [timthumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/) for this. Just giving another option ;)